# Updating large MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a table of 10000 product in my MySQL database. I would like to update all the records in a fastest way. I am using Laravel with MySQL.

For better solution I can change technologies also. Right now it takes almost half hour to update the whole table.

I would like to update that table in a fastest way. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I am using Laravel model like below

```
DB::table('products')->where('product_id',$product_id)->limit(1)->update(array('prodcut_quantity' => $prodcut_quantity));
```

Comment: Update them all in one statement? If you're doing a single update at a time, it will take bloody foreveer.

Comment: What is the update command that you are using ?

Comment: Please show us what code you are using so that we may help.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King, I provided some code.

Comment: Nice :) If you supply code regarding where `$product_id` and `$product_quantity` are coming from I might be able to create some pseudo code to expand on my answer.

Comment: Your culprit here is not php, nor laravel. It's your approach and MySQL configuration. When a database is slow to do the work, it's usually the *database's* fault. Reason why the db is at fault is because it has to write constantly, and you forced it to write one record at a time. One update will spend 1 I/O operation - you have about 150-200 of those per second, so for 10k records it will take a while. Solutions include: faster hard drive, wrapping those silly updates in a big transaction or simply create one big update statement (or several smaller updates that update many products at once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a loop that adds the primary key and product quantity into an array then do a `DB::insert` and enter an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` query (such as below) replacing the values with the ones in the arrays:

```
$array = array(
    '1,1', //product_id,product_quantity
    '2,2',
    '4,12',
);

DB::insert('INSERT INTO products (product_id,product_quantity) VALUES (' . implode('),(', $array) . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_quantity=VALUES(product_quantity)');
```

This query will attempt to `INSERT` the `product_id` and `product_quantity` into the `products` table. As the `product_id` will already exist the query changes to an `UPDATE`, with us mapping what we want the column `product_quantity` to be.

Comment: Despite being the selected answer, this approach **is not** the fastest way to perform an update using Laravel (or anything else). Anyone coming from google and arriving at this answer should have this in mind. It's also a complete anti-pattern and it just adds overhead for no reason, there's nothing wrong with performing a simple update and wrapping multiple of those in a single transaction to make it faster (because that's how we make things faster - we use one input output operation to write a lot of data to the disk, which is why hdds boast with bandwith measurement).

Comment: Thanks @N.B. for your reply. Could you please show us more faster way ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there are two answers that tell you how to do it faster. Also, there are comments that are telling you how to do it faster. If you are fishing for copy/paste solution that you can use - I'm afraid you won't get one.

Comment: Thanks @N.B. for your quick response. Now I am thinking about Cache. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Performance is more often affected by the table design than the statement being run against it.  Make sure that your table is properly indexed and is using an efficient storage engine and make sure that your data is normalised.  As mentioned in the comments, make sure you are using a single update query rather than multiple ones (or at the very least as few statements as you can possible use). If you are looking for code optimisation then you will need to post some up for us to work with.  If you could post up details of your table design, indexes and storage engine it would also be a help.

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastest way is to use **single-line update command inside your database management interface(like phpmyadmin)** in this way:

```
UPDATE product SET ...
```

I have used it for 1 million record before and get the result after about 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @hamed for your response. Are you talking about construct an update SQL Query using loop, then execute that Query ??

Comment: You are welcome. No, no need to use loop. You can update your table with just **one query** in your database management interface(not inside your project).